# Compiled typescript files to javascript files: Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've just started learning and developing an application in Angular 2. The typescript language we use for development is really interesting but I have a question regarding data types in typescript.
 Since typescript files are compiled to javascript, how are the data types compiled in javascript?

For example:

```
sample.ts
value_a : String;
```

the above is a sample typescript file which declares a variable of type String. When we compile this typescript file, this gets compiled into a javascript file. Now how will the datatype of this variable defined in the javascript file (as per my knowledge you can't define datatypes in javascript, it automatically determines the datatype when you assign some value to that variable).

Answer (score 0):

Types in typescript are used purely by the compiler to know what restrictions it should enforce. You've never assigned a value to `value_a`, so its type at runtime would be `undefined`. If you were to have instead said

```
value_a :string = 'hello';
```

then the type of `value_a` would be `string`.

While still in typescript, if you were to try to say

```
value_a = 4;
```

the compiler would complain at you. However, once you're dealing with the compiled javascript the typical javascript rules apply and you can happily assign `4` to `value_a`.

---

Note: For completeness I should mention there are somewhat complicated runtime type information mechanisms when using reflect-metadata and a couple compiler flags but that's obscure until you know more about angular 2. The TLDR is there isn't any type information at runtime beyond normal javascript. Any info you want you'll have to pin to objects yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript data types easy our programs by defining data type to each variable. Significance of data types are within Typescript only. When compiled to javascript, it will be `undefined` irrespective of what data type it was assigned in Typescript. When you play with the variables in your code, you know what will be it's data type and it helps to code.

Let's say if you write this code in Typescript-

```
value_a : String = "ABC";
value_a : number = 123;

value_a = value_b  //This will throw compile time error in Typescript, But In Javascript, this is fine
```